# Css equivalents for xpath axes

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Could you someone tell me css equivalents for following xpath axes?

```
 1. ancestor
 2. descendant
 3. following
 4. following-sibling
 5. preceding
 6. preceding-sibling
```

So that I can have css alternatives for xpaths like followings:

```
 1. //table/descendant::td/input
 2. //td/following-sibling::td
```

Comment: you can refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) to know about selectors

Comment: I don't believe there are exact matches to that in CSS. If you want to do this much movement within the DOM, XPath is probably your only way. For instance there is no concept of a "parent" in CSS selectors.

Comment: Thanks Amith and Arran! Final conclusion, I can draw is 'in some situations, xpath is the only way to locate element'

Comment: If you can add specific classes to the elements you are trying to select, then CSS selectors can work very nicely.